# Handling Identical IO Exceptions In Different Code Blocks

Tags: c#, winforms, architecture, exception, io

I'm working on a WinForms project that involves multiple IO calls. With IO comes great responsibility as many IO methods are fairly prone to exceptions (UnauthorizedAccess/file in use/etc.).

I'd like to know how to best handle the same exceptions throughout multiple spots in the code. For example, if I call `FileInfo.CopyTo()` in 7 different code blocks, all of which could throw `UnauthorizedAccessException`s, how should I handle that? I know that the general consensus dictates that exceptions should only be caught when they can be properly handled. I'm unsure of a "proper" way to handle an `UnauthorizedAccessException`, but I do want to display a `MessageBox` informing the user that the file was not copied.

In this case, I would have to wrap the 7 calls to `CopyTo()` in a `try`/`catch` statement and pop up the same `MessageBox` 7 times. To avoid reusing code, my first thought is to create something like this:

```
public void SafeCopy(FileInfo file, string targetPath)
    {
        try
        {
            file.CopyTo(targetPath);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This is obviously simplified and would handle additional exceptions. However, it doesn't quite feel right to create a "wrapper method" simply designed to handle exceptions for a single method call.

I know this could be considered subjective, but I feel there is a correct answer or alternate path here.

Comment: I would say, is the exception actually helpful to the user?  If not then I'd wrap them into a signature like `bool TryCopyTo()`.  Let it handle the exception logging etc, and let whatever made the call know if it was successful or not.

Comment: but that is actually a good thing to do.

Comment: @ErikPhilips In my mind, the exception is helpful to the user as it allows them to possibly resolve issues the application can't. For example, if the exception reveals that it is an access violation, they can check security settings for the file. If the file is being used by another process, they can close that process.

Comment: What you've done is perfectly acceptable, it's good code.